# extract substring from lines using grep, awk,sed or etc

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a files with many lines like:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/airuike" class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name " data-sessionlink="ei=CKPW6LXqqbQCFSqVIQod_BwsaQ%3D%3D" dir="ltr">lily weisy</a>
```

I want to extract www.youtube.com/user/airuike and lily weisy, and then I also want to separate airuike from www.youtube.com/user/

so I want to get  3 strings: www.youtube.com/user/airuike, airuike and lily weisy

how to achieve this? thanks

Comment: Do you have to use awk or grep?  There are better ways to parse HTML.

Comment: [Google](http://google.com) is a great resource for learning how to do things that you don't know how to do.

Comment: [Regex are not for HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/76722), use an actual HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this:

```
sed -e 's/.*href="\([^"]*\)".*>\([^<]*\)<.*/link:\1 name:\2/' < data
```

will give you the first part. But I'm not sure what you are doing with it after this.

Comment: what if a developer writes `<!-- <a href=...`?

Comment: the first .* will skip everything up to the href, so it should still work.

Comment: but _should_ it work? of course it is unclear by the question, but I believe that regex are simply not the right job for HTML, except in one-shot-hacks (but not as part of real projects)

Comment: oh, I don't disagree with that. but the question was asking for sed. I'd rather pull it into something that can parse the DOM, but that wasn't question.  So it will work on the given string, in another context who knows

Answer (score 1):

Since it is html, and html should be parsed with a html parser and not with grep/sed/awk, you could use the pattern matching function of my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html).

```
 xidel yourfile.html -e '<a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name " dir="ltr">{$link := @href, $user := substring-after($link, "www.youtube.com/user/"), $name:=text()}</a>*'
```

Or if you want a CSV like result:

```
 xidel yourfile.html -e '<a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name " dir="ltr">{string-join((@href, substring-after(@href, "www.youtube.com/user/"), text()), ", ")}</a>*' --hide-variable-names
```

---

It is kind of sad, that you also want to have the airuike string, otherwise it could be as simple as

```
xidel /yourfile.html  -e '<a href="{$link}" class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name ">{$name}</a>*'
```

(and you were supposed to be able to use `xidel '<a href="{$link:=., $user := filter($link, www.youtube.com/user/(.*)\', 1)}" class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name " dir="ltr">{$name}</a>*'`, but it seems I haven't thought the syntax through. Just  *one* error check and it is breaking everything. )

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{split($0,a,/(["<>]|:\/\/)/); u=a[4]; sub(/.*\//,"",a[4]); print u,a[4],a[12]}' file
www.youtube.com/user/airuike airuike lily weisy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this must work

```
while read line
do
    href=$(echo $line | grep -o 'http[^"]*')
    user=$(echo $href | grep -o '[^/]*$')
    text=$(echo $line | grep -o '[^>]*<\/a>$' | grep -o '^[^<]*')

    echo href: $href
    echo user: $user
    echo text: $text
done < yourfile
```

Regular expressions basics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions

Upd: checked and fixed

Comment: will this not also match `<strong>Lucy's new "http-parser"!</strong>`?

Comment: you are right, but I've supposed that the formatting was homogenic. If you know that all lines are in the same format, the regex can be simpler